# Deployed django app to heroku missing CSS / static files

Tags: python, django, heroku

Preface this by saying I have now read multiple posts on this question (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961177/heroku-static-files-not-loading-django?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121663/static-files-not-found-deploying-django-on-heroku?rq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825443/django-heroku-static-dir?rq=1)). What I understand is that the `static url` in `settings.py` needs a modification for heroku to run these static files. What I need, explained like I am a child, is what tweak to make to these `static url` when the static directory is nested within the app -- as this was a best practice imparted in a recent tutorial (if this is not the ideal practice I would appreciate being corrected).

**Question 1:** Should the `media` files be kept in a directory within the app or at the project level?

**Question 2:** If the media files are kept within a directory inside the app, like my directory below, then how am I supposed to modify the `url` in `settings.py` to load the static files once pushed to heroku?

My project structure is the following:

```
gvlabs
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    settings.py
    settings.pyc
    urls.py
    urls.pyc
    wsgi.py
    wsgi.pyc
manage.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
welcome
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    admin.py
    admin.pyc
    apps.py
    hello.py
    migrations
    models.py
    models.pyc
    static
        css
        fonts
        images
        js
    templates
        welcome
            base.html
            comingsoon.html
            contact_us.html
            index.html
            post_list.html
    tests.py
    urls.py
    urls.pyc
    views.py
    views.pyc
```

**settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'../welcome')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/welcome/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The main problem with your configuration is the `STATIC_ROOT` setting. You should change this to something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')`.

   `STATIC_ROOT` should point to an empty directory (it doesn't need to exist, Django will create it if necessary) where Django can collect your static files together and do any necessary processing on them before it serves them. It is **not** the directory where you store your static files.
2. Regardless of where you put your static files, you shouldn't need to change the `STATIC_URL` setting. Just leave it as `/static/`. The main reason for needing to change this is when you're serving static files via a CDN, when it would be set to something like `https://my-cdn.example.com/static/`
3. I would keep static files in a directory at the project level. Sometimes, when creating a reusable app it makes sense to bundle everything together by storing its static files in a directory within the app. But most projects I've worked on have kept the main set of static files at the project level.
4. It doesn't really matter where you put your static files as long as you tell Django where to find them. You do this by adding the path to the directory to the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting like so:

   ```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
   ]
   ```

   (Technically, if your static files are in an app directory Django should be able to find them automatically, but let's keep things simple and explicit.)
5. As a side note: be careful not to use the term "media" here as that has a specific meaning in Django terminology where it refers to [user-uploaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) files like profile images rather than files that belong with your codebase like CSS and JavaScript files.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. This did the trick. Good to know about distinction around media and the other tidbits of insight.